# Overwriting contents of files

Tags: javascript, node.js, file

I have a file `index.js` inside that i have a function

```js
const local = function() {
    return {
      person: {
        name: "man",
        age: 24,
        city: "Mumbai",
      },
    };
  };
```

I have another file `index1.txt` in that i have the same object `person:{name:'qwe'}`. I need to overwrite the object in `index.js` with text present in `index1.txt`. My file `index.js` should look like this

```js
const local = function() {
    return {
      person: {
        name: "qwe",
        age: 24,
        city: "Mumbai",
      },
    };
  };`
```

can anyone help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

Use **object assign** method...

```
const local = function() {
    return {
      person: {
        name: "man",
        age: 24,
        city: "Mumbai",
      },
    };
  };

const local2 = function() {
    return {
      person: {
        name: "qwe",
        age: 24,
        city: "Mumbai",
      },
    };
  };

const result= Object.assign(local, local2);
```

Comment: where to use this? second file is my text file. It returns me a string after i read the contents of it.

Answer (score 0):

Example [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/intelligent-pond-vlmfe). It shows how to import and how to merge the imported person.
import

```
import data from "./index1.json";

const local = function() {
  return {
    person: {
      name: "man",
      age: 24,
      city: "Mumbai",
      ...data.person
    }
  };
};
```

Comment: Actually the requirement is i can't import the file inside it. I need to make it generic like if any txt file with same object properties should replace the content. Need to read the file contents using readFileasync method.

Comment: theres too much variability. you should not scan all folder contents and check for data shape.

Comment: yeah i am searching for the better approach. I am finding the solution considering both the files are text files.